# Failing jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've just started working with jQuery and love it. I'm having a problem with an ajax call though, and I was wondering if anyone could help me out. Here's my ajax call:

```
//start the ajax
    $.ajax({
        //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
        url: "php/login.php",   

        //GET method is used
        type: "GET",

        //pass the data         
        data: data,     

        //Do not cache the page
        //cache: false,

        //success
        success: function (html) {              
            //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
            if (html==1) {                  
                //hide the form
                alert( html );
                $('.form').fadeOut('slow');                 

                //show the success message
                $('.done').fadeIn('slow');

              //if process.php returned 0/false (send mail failed)
              } else alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.' + html);              
    },

    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, request, error){
      alert('xrs.status = ' + xhr.status + '\n' + 
            'thrown error = ' + thrownError + '\n' +
            'xhr.statusText = '  + xhr.statusText + '\n' +
            'request = ' + request + '\n' +
            'error = ' + error);
      }       


    });
```

and here's my output:

xrs.status = 200
thrown error = undefined
xhr.statusText = OK
request = undefined
error = undefined

my php looks like:

```
<?php

//turn on error reporting, set header
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
header('Content-Type: text/xml');

//pull variables
//Need to do some error checking here
$username = $_GET['name'];
$password = $_GET['pass'];

//connect with database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
//if connection unsuccessful
if(!$con){
  //stop, and display error
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("musicneverstopped", $con);
//end connecting to database

//query database for user-submitted username and store result in $result
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");

//if no results returned
if(!$result){
  //stop and display error
  die(mysql_error());
  }

//check if a single result was returned
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){
  //if true, set the returned results to $row
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  //check if password from user matches password from database
  if($password == $row['password']){
    //if true, begin session
    session_start();
    //assign session variables
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['privilege'] = $row['privlege'];
    //send user to index page
    //header('Location: http://localhost/musicneverstopped');
    mysql_close($con);//close mysql connection
    return 1;
    }
  else{
    mysql_close($con);//close mysql connection
    //if false, send user to login page
    return 0;
    }
  mysql_close($con);
  }//end if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
else{
  mysql_close($con);//close mysql connection
  return 0;
  }
?>
```

I know it's not production quality, but it looks like it should work...

Anyone see why the error function is firing? All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. Dan

Comment: What happens if you comment out your success function?

Comment: You're getting request and error = undefined because the error function only takes three arguments. See http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options

Comment: If you look at the response in firebug, what's it look like?

Comment: removed ajaxOptions, and thrownError from parameters and new output is: xrs.status = 200
xhr.statusText = OK
request = parsererror
error = undefined

Comment: So the request is returning a parse error...

Comment: Commenting out success doesn't change anything...

Comment: Maybe you're supposed to post to this url instead of get? Does a get request work from the browser?

Comment: Can we see an example of the data variable?

Comment: var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&pass=' + pass.val();

Comment: The weird thing is it logs me in, it just doesn't fire the success handler...

Comment: David is correct, the error callback function is supposed to take 3 args. From the docs: error: A function to be called if the request fails. The function is passed three arguments: The XMLHttpRequest object, a string describing the type of error that occurred, and an optional exception object, if one occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could add the `dataType` parameter (passing "text" as the datatype) to your .ajax call... I usually get a `parsererror` when getting back malformed XML or JSON. When you don't set the `dataType`, jquery tries to automatically determine if the response is XML or HTML. Perhaps this is failing, since your response is neither? See http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options

Comment: That was the answer! Works perfect now. Thanks Funka

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a debugging question, I'll suggest going meta here, and investigating other tools than just a plain browser page:

1. Use Firebug (getfirebug.com) or Safari/Chrome's webkit inspector:
   http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Web%20Inspector
2. Learn how to use said tools, especially the Net(firebug) or Resources(webkit) panels.
3. Look at the actual request and response values
4. Take Randell's advice an use "print_r()" to debug your php code.  I inject the following into my code, and uncomment as needed for debugging things like my SQL call, or the data value before it gets JSON'd, etc:

> `die("<pre>".print_r($phpvariable,true)."</pre>");`

Answer (score 1):

/* stop form from submitting normally */

`event.preventDefault();`

/* get some values from elements on the page: */

`var val = $(this).serialize();`

/* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */

`$.ajax({`

   `url: "newsletter.php",`

   `type: "post",`

   `data: val,`

   `datatype: 'json',`

   `success: function(data){`

      `alert('SUCCESS');`

   `},`

   `error:function(){`

      `alert("ERROR");`

   `}`

`});`

Answer (score 0):

If the request is returning a parser error, then it sounds like the problem is server side. Perhaps improper serialization? Check out your login.php file.